# How place background-image to the top of the div with padding

Tags: html, css

In Html I've this code

```
<div class="page">
        <div id="header">
            ...
        </div>
</div>
```

And here is my css

```
.page {
    width: 1028px;
    background-color:#103250;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

#header
{
    background:url('/Img/SubpageBox1.png') no-repeat top;
    height:150px;
    padding-top:50px;
}
```

But now my background-image is placed out of div... On the top of the page... How can I place it on the top of the header?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can specify the position of the background image:

```
background:url('/Img/SubpageBox1.png') no-repeat center 50px;
```

or using [`background-position`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-position.asp) css property.

Comment: using pure css - yes :). If I understand correct: you need to move your bg image to the 50 px down, not on the top, right?